# MPI_Irecv does not receive all sends?

Tags: c++, openmpi

What I am trying to acheive in this simplified code is:

- 2 types of processes (root, and children, ids/rank = 10 and 0-9 respectively)
- init:

  - root will listen to children "completed"
  - children will listen to root notification when all has completed
- while there is no winner (not all done yet):

  - children will have 20% chance they will be done (and notify root they are done)
  - root will check that all are done

    - if all done: send notification to children of "winner"

I have code like:

```
int numprocs, id, arr[10], winner = -1;
bool stop = false;
MPI_Request reqs[10], winnerNotification;

MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

for (int half = 0; half < 1; half++) {
    for (int round = 0; round < 1; round++) {
        if (id == 10) { // root
            // keeps track of who has "completed"
            fill_n(arr, 10, -1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                MPI_Irecv(&arr[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]);
            }
        } else if (id < 10) { // children
            // listen to root of winner notification/indication to stop
            MPI_Irecv(&winner, 1, MPI_INT, 10, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &winnerNotification);
        }

        while (winner == -1) {
            //cout << id << " is in loop" << endl;

            if (id < 10 && !stop && ((rand() % 10) + 1) < 3) { 
                // children has 20% chance to stop (finish work)
                MPI_Send(&id, 1, MPI_INT, 10, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                cout << id << " sending to root" << endl;
                stop = true;
            } else if (id == 10) {
                // root checks number of children completed
                int numDone = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (arr[i] >= 0) {
                        //cout << "root knows that " << i << " has completed" << endl;
                        numDone++;
                    }
                }
                cout << "numDone = " << numDone << endl;

                // if all done, send notification to players to stop
                if (numDone == 10) {
                    winner = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        MPI_Send(&winner, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    }
                    cout << "root sent notification of winner" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

Output from debugging `cout`s look like: problem seems to be root is not receiving all childrens notification that they are completed?

```
2 sending to root
3 sending to root
0 sending to root
4 sending to root
1 sending to root
8 sending to root
9 sending to root
numDone = 1
numDone = 1
... // many numDone = 1, but why 1 only?
7 sending to root
...
```

I thought perhaps I can't receive into an array: but I tried

```
if (id == 1) {
    int x = 60;
    MPI_Send(&x, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (id == 0) {
    MPI_Recv(&arr[1], 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    cout << id << " recieved " << arr[1] << endl;
}
```

Which works.

**UPDATE**

This seems to be resolved if I add a `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)` before the end of the while loop, but why? Even if the processes run out of sync, eventually, children will send to root that they have completed and root should "listen" to that and process accordingly? What seems to be happening is root keeps running, hogging up all resources for children to execute at all? Or whats happening here?

**UPDATE 2: some children not getting notification from root**

Ok now the problem that root does not receive children's notification that they have completed by @MichaelSh's answer, I focus on children not receiving from parent. Here's a code that reproduces that problem:

```
int numprocs, id, arr[10], winner = -1;
bool stop = false;
MPI_Request reqs[10], winnerNotification;

MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

srand(time(NULL) + id);

if (id < 10) {
    MPI_Irecv(&winner, 1, MPI_INT, 10, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &winnerNotification);
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

while (winner == -1) {
    cout << id << " is in loop ..." << endl;
    if (id == 10) {
        if (((rand() % 10) + 1) < 2) {
            winner = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                MPI_Send(&winner, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            cout << "winner notifications sent" << endl;
        }
    }
}

cout << id << " b4 MPI_Finalize. winner is " << winner << endl;

MPI_Finalize();
```

Output looks like:

```
# 1 run
winner notifications sent
10 b4 MPI_Finalize. winner is 2
9 b4 MPI_Finalize. winner is 2
0 b4 MPI_Finalize. winner is 2

# another run
winner notifications sent
10 b4 MPI_Finalize. winner is 2
8 b4 MPI_Finalize. winner is 2
```

Notice some processes doesnt seem to get the notification from the parent? Why is that, `MPI_Wait` for child processes will just hang them? So how do I resolve this?

Also

> All `MPI_Barrier` does in your case -- it waits for child responses to complete. Please check my answer for a better solution

If I dont do this, I suppose each child response will just take few ms? So even if I dont wait/barrier, I'd expect the receive to still happen soon after the send? Unless processes end up hogging resources and other processes does not run?

Comment: Can you trace how many times `MPI_Irecv(&arr[i],...)` is called?

Comment: @MichaelSh, From the code, it should be 10 times (once for each child), for each round? I added a cout after the irecv and true enough, its called 10 times

Comment: What about `MPI_Wait`, don't you have to call it before accessing `arr`. In your example that works you use blocking send/receive but in your app you use async receive...

Comment: Hmm... I think the thing is I dont really want to "wait", I need the loop to continue if there are incomplete processes (if I wait, the loop will not continue?). I am under the impression the root checking the arr on every loop should work? Meaning at some point in time, the arr should be filled with results from completed `Irecv`?

Comment: @MichaelSh, it appears it works when I add an `MPI_Barrier()` as described in update to post, but why?

Comment: All `MPI_Barrier` does in your case -- it waits for child responses to complete. Please check my answer for a better solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19666/discussion-between-jiew-meng-and-michael-sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this block of code (error checking omitted for simplicity):

```
...
// root checks number of children completed
int numDone = 0;
MPI_Status statuses[10];
MPI_Waitall(10, reqs, statuses);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
...
```

**Edit** A better solution:
Each child initiates root winner notification receipt and sends its notification to the root.
Root initiates winner notification receipt to the array and goes into wait for all notifications to be received, and then sends winner's id to children.
Insert this code below after `for (int round = 0; round < 1; round++)`

```
            if (id == 10) 
            { // root
                // keeps track of who has "completed"
                memset(arr, -1, sizeof(arr));
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
                {
                    MPI_Irecv(&arr[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]);
                }
            } 
            else if (id < 10) 
            { // children
                // listen to root of winner notification/indication to stop
                MPI_Irecv(&winner, 1, MPI_INT, 10, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &winnerNotification);
            }

            if (id < 10)
            {
                while(((rand() % 10) + 1) < 3) ;

                // children has 20% chance to stop (finish work)
                MPI_Send(&id, 1, MPI_INT, 10, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                std::cout << id << " sending to root" << std::endl;
                // receive winner notification
                MPI_Status status;
                MPI_Wait(&winnerNotification, &status);
                // Process winner notification
            } 
            else if (id == 10) 
            {
                MPI_Status statuses[10];
                MPI_Waitall(10, reqs, statuses);                    

                // if all done, send notification to players to stop
                {
                    winner = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
                    {
                        MPI_Send(&winner, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    }
                    std::cout << "root sent notification of winner" << std::endl;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hmm makes sense, sort of ... can be kind of confusing, ... but now it seems like the children are not receiving the winner "notifications", thus continue to be in infinite loop, if I try to wait the loop will not proceed at all (as expected) ...

Comment: Should we continue discussion in chat?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19666/discussion-between-jiew-meng-and-michael-sh?

Comment: "(error checking omitted for simplicity)". Actually, checking for errors in simple MPI programs is pointless as the MPI standard mandates, that the default error handler abort the program execution. Hence MPI calls either return `MPI_SUCCESS` or simply do not return (as the program terminates). One has to explicitly change the error handler of each communicator to `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN` in order to receive MPI status codes from failed calls.